# WorkManager PeriodicWorkRequest doesn't work when app closed

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-workmanager

I need to create notifications when app is closed, I try to do follow method:

NotificationWorker:

```
class NotificationWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    private lateinit var notificationManager: NotificationManager


    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        initNotifications()
        notificationManager.notify(0, createNotification())
        return Result.success()
    }

    private fun initNotifications() {
        notificationManager = getSystemService(
            applicationContext,
            NotificationManager::class.java
        ) as NotificationManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            val channel =
                NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL, importance)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }

    private fun createNotification(): Notification {
        val builder = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            Notification.Builder(applicationContext) else
            Notification.Builder(applicationContext, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)

        builder.apply {
            setContentTitle("Current time")
            setContentText("${Calendar.getInstance()}")
            setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
        }
        return builder.build()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL = "syncended.news"

        private fun getWorkerRequest(): PeriodicWorkRequest =
            PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<NotificationWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build()


        fun enqueueSelf(context: Context) {
            WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                NotificationWorker::class.java.name,
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                getWorkerRequest()
            )
        }
    }
}
```

On Recieve call `NotificationWorker.enqueueSelf(context)`

Main activity calling in onCreate `sendBroadcast(Intent(this,NotificationsStartReceiver::class.java))`

Application:

```
class News : Application(), Configuration.Provider {
    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
        Configuration.Builder()
            .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.INFO)
            .build()
}
```

I've created reciever and provider in Manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
    android:exported="false"
    tools:node="remove" />
<receiver
    android:name=".notifications.NotificationsStartReceiver"
    android:process=":newsBgNotify" />
```

When app is running it's ok, but when I've closed app (in task manager), I've got next, and notifications didn't shown

```
2020-05-04 15:06:26.678 2046-2159/system_process W/InputDispatcher: channel '68c8279 ru.syncended.news/ru.syncended.news.main.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
2020-05-04 15:06:26.679 2046-2159/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '68c8279 ru.syncended.news/ru.syncended.news.main.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Answer (score 1):

Some Chinese OEM mobile phones(*like Oppo*) kill the apps(*stop the background services*) after the user swipes off an app from the recent apps tab. This is the main reason for this. To prevent these devices from doing so, go to settings -> App settings -> "YourApp" and "Enable background services"